# ANDROID ONTOUCH LISTENER

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, onclicklistener

I'm having a problem in setontouchLister i'm trying to play a 10sec clip when a button is clicked and when i remove my finger from it it should stop...
i've tried but on touch it played and never stop till the time ends i.e 10sec overs Please help!!
here is my code

```
MediaPlayer mp;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.m_b);
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.gm);




      btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {


            @Override

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {

                    mp.start();

                    return true;
                }


                return true;
            }

        });

}

@Override 

protected void onPause() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onPause();

    mp.release();

    finish();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
        mp.start();
        return true;
    }
    else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {
        mp.stop();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: It not even working any more i mean The button is not playing any sound

Comment: @OsamaAftab you need to call start() on DOWN and stop() on UP, see revised code sample

Comment: yeah i got that just a min ago just did the same way

Comment: When you lift your finger is ACTION_UP not called, or is mp.stop() not stopping the MediaPlayer? To see what's happening you can run tests with `Log.d("tag", action);` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You just stop when the touch listener sends an ACTION_UP event.

```
if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {
    mp.stop();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It not even working any more i mean The button is not playing any sound